# Jquery .animate not working for fixed position

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my .animate function

```
<script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
$('#slide').click(function(){
$('#2guns').animate({right: 500},10000);
});
});
</script>
```

And this is the element I'm animating

```
 <div class="content">
            <button id="slide">slide</button>
           <img src="/home/varun/Documents/Crown/images/line.png" id="2guns" STYLE="position:absolute;left:1293px;">
        </div>
```

It works perfectly without the attribute

```
left:1293px;
```

Any solutions?

Comment: can you try lower case style instead of STYLE use style?

Comment: Create a class in your css file and add the class on your element. I'm not sure but I suppose that because you already have inline defined left animate cant change it.

Comment: If you specify both `left` and `right`, it will stretch the element to match both properties. If you want to **move** the element using `right` you will need to remove the `left`.

Comment: This isn't a fixed position - it's an absolute position. There is a difference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/kD3Zt/

```
 <div class="content">
        <button id="slide">slide</button>
       <img src="/home/varun/Documents/Crown/images/line.png" id="2guns" STYLE="position:absolute;left:1293px;">
    </div>
```

---

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#slide').click(function(){
 $('#2guns').animate({left: 200},10000);
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead, element can't have both left and right as style

```
$('#2guns').animate({left: 500},10000);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mCGED/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to give left, please specify...

I tried it with right and it works fine...

```
<div class="content">
            <button id="slide">slide</button>
           <img src="/home/varun/Documents/Crown/images/line.png" id="2guns" STYLE="position:absolute; right:0px;">
        </div>
```